# How can we define multi-dimensional norms?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

How can we define multi-dimensional norms?
For example,

$$ \| (v_1, v_2, \cdots , v_n) \|_{W^{1,2}(X)} \;\;\text{or} \;\;\|(v_1 , v_2 , \cdots , v_n ) \|_{L^2 (X)}$$ for some appropriate functions $v_i$'s.

Comment: Sorry, but.. What do you mean by "*multi-dimensional*" norm?

Comment: @Berci I mean the norm of a function with several components.

Comment: It might be easier if you give a specific example of what you are interested in. Are you asking how the specific norms you mentioned are defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, you would use some standard norms like in $\mathbb{R}^n$. For instance,
$$
\|(u,v)\|_{L^2} = \sqrt{\|u\|_{L^2}^2 + \|v\|_{L^2}^2}
$$
or
$$
\|(u,v)\|_{L^2} = \|u\|_{L^2} + \|v\|_{L^2}
$$